# Desktop (dual boot with windows) with AMD GPU upgraded from ubuntu 18LTS to 20.04 LTS breaks login GUI

Tags: drivers, 20.04, login, login-screen, display-manager

I made the mistake of upgrading from ubuntu 18 LTS to 20.04 LTS not knowing there are (login) issues with 20.04.

My computer has an

- AMD GPU
- dual boot with windows
- ~5 gigabytes of space left available on the ubuntu partition

I have had past history with issues with lightdm, desktop environments and logging in. However prior to upgrading I had a relatively functioning system.

When I initially upgraded there was a failure due to lack of diskspace. I had boot issues and ran boot repair from a 20.04 LTS live disk (on a USB stick). [ubuntu paste of boot repair](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/Hr2bNjzJ8p/) Boot seem repaired fine, as I can make it to the login screen now.

The current state and things I can do

- running `df -h` notes my `$HOME` directory has 5gb of space (94% in use)
- enter recovery mode from GRUB
- enter TTY3 on login screen if I'm quick enough
- try to use the login screen, but the login screen freezes within a few seconds and won't accept keyboard or mouse inputs
- if I manage to enter login credentials quickly enough at the login screen, I am sent to a black screen
- run `startx` from TTY3 which then puts me into a black screen where I can right click to get a menu, open a terminal but the GUI is only partially working

Some of the things I've tried, that didn't work to fix it

- installing lightdm from the terminal and switching to that from gdm3
- tried updating AMD GPU drivers (method 2 here: https://linuxconfig.org/amd-radeon-ubuntu-20-04-driver-installation `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers` followed by `sudo apt update && sudo apt -y upgrade`
- tried changing the desktop environment? `sudo update-alternatives --config x-session-manager` , however this appears to perhaps not change the setting in the bottom right of the GUI login screen? I have not managed to persist changing that setting manually in the GUI , as the computer freezes before I can restart the computer after changing this setting and remains stuck on `Ubuntu` regardless of what changing `sudo update-alternatives --config x-session-manager` or changing it in the GUI login screen before the computer freezes.
- `sudo apt autoremove` (there is nothing to remove from this command at TTY3 or doing the equivalent from recovery mode I believe)
- `free -m` from TTY3 says there is free space in mem and swap

From TTY 3

sudo mv ~/.Xauthority ~/.Xauthority.backup
sudo service lightdm restart

Gets me to a login screen but once I try to login it breaks

What additional pieces of diagnostic information can I gather and what can I do to fix this?

Comment: @guiverc yes 20.04 LTS , thank you for clarifying. I have tried checking $HOME's space by running `df -h` , if this was a correct way to do it, there is space

Answer (score 0):

As you are able to access TTY3 you could try to uninstall some software you do not need. You can start with:

```
sudo apt autoremove
```

You can also try "ncdu" CLI utility to find what is taking your space. Just run it from / directory. Maybe you find some old backups or files you do not need. [Here](https://www.unixmen.com/ncdu-ncurses-disk-usage-analyzer/) more on how to use ncdu.

What is your RAM usage when you log in?

```
free -m
```

I once tried to boot with Graphical environment into RAM and because of its size, it was too slow and eventually, it got stuck...

Comment: Updated my question, nothing to autoremove (I believe I ran that in the past anyway) and free -m notes there should be plenty of ram available (7067), let me know if you have any other recommendations, thanks

Comment: Can you identify what is using your cpu?
ps aux --sort=-pcpu | head

Comment: Do you get some hints from: 
`journalctl | grep error | tail -n 20`? Can you run `sudo apt update` `sudo apt upgrade`?

Comment: I also found this [link](https://letsfoss.com/ubuntu-20-04-login-loop-fix/)

Comment: Tried those upgrade commands before, I'm in a different state of error now after running some recovery mode actions https://askubuntu.com/questions/1330800/ubuntu-regular-boot-from-grub-black-screen-safe-mode-into-regular-boot-mode-wor